# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entities

I get this error when I try this code :

```
TaxiEntities db = new TaxiEntities();
bool IsUserPassCorrected = db.tblOperators.Any(item => item.UserName.ToLower() == txtUserName.Text.ToLower() &&
item.Password == Convert.ToInt32(txtPassWord.Text));

if (!IsUserPassCorrected)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Username or Password is incorrected! Please try again");
}
```

Comment: use brackets and parse/tryparse

Comment: On a side note, if your db is not case-sensitive you could leave out the `.ToLower()` which makes it cleaner to read. Also don't forget to `Dispose` your context which is best done wrapped inside a `using` block.

Answer (score 7):

Since LINQ to Entities does not support `Convert.ToInt32`, you need to parse to `int` outside LINQ first:

```
TaxiEntities db = new TaxiEntities();
int password = int.Parse(txtPassWord.Text);

bool IsUserPassCorrected = db.tblOperators
            .Any(item => item.UserName.ToLower() == txtUserName.Text.ToLower() 
                      && item.Password == password);
```